# Mysql Trigger- Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

i want to use triggers. when i update my table i want to swap some of data to other table.

i create trigger but when i update i get this error: Result consisted of more than one row

```
CREATE TRIGGER ilk AFTER UPDATE ON garanti 

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE total INT DEFAULT 0; 

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total FROM garanti group by il; 

INSERT INTO il_stat ( `id` , `il` , `sayi` ) VALUES ( NULL , '3', 'total' ); 

END;
```

this is result of my query, i want to insert this to other table(after update on main table):

--city--,--count--

london, 56

berlin, 65

istanbul, 76
...,..
...,..

Comment: If you use `group by` you will get more than one `total`. And since you have only 1 variable that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your select returns more than one row. Remove the INTO part and see it for yourself.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM garanti group by il;
```